# Compiling report function in matlab 2008 returns error

Tags: matlab, deployment, executable

I'm trying to create matlab executable for building a report.

 My function is

```
function custom_report( FilePath )
report('MyReport.rpt', ['-o' FilePath],'-fpdf') ;
```

but the deploytool retrun error when trying to build this standalone executable (exe file).
What can be the cause of this problem?

p.s. I attached the 'MyReport.rpt' file to the deploytool project, so it's probably not the cause.

```
% Deploytool Build Errors:
Error C:\Algo\customreport\src\customreport_main.c: 16  syntax error; found `__MCC_customreport_component_data' expecting `;' 
Error C:\Algo\customreport\src\customreport_main.c: 103  left operand of . has incompatible type `int' 
Error C:\Algo\customreport\src\customreport_main.c: 103  operands of = have illegal types `int' and `pointer to char' 
Error C:\Algo\customreport\src\customreport_main.c: 117  left operand of . has incompatible type `int' 
Error C:\Algo\customreport\src\customreport_main.c: 117  type error in argument 1 to `mclInitializeApplication_proxy'; found `int' expected `pointer to pointer to const char' 
Error C:\Algo\customreport\src\customreport_main.c: 118  left operand of . has incompatible type `int'
```